# How to get the value using XPath and using Parameter?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am making BDD-testing using c#, SpecFlow and Selenium.
I want to create method to click the button. Name of this button should be taken from parameter (string p0), like this:

> ```
>     [Given(@"I click (.*) button")]
>     public void GivenIClickButton(string p0)
>     {
>         //Find button p0 and Click on it
>     }
> ```

Using XPath I can do Only this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Get Started Now!')]")).Click();
```

But I would like to do something more like this:

> driver.FindElement(By.Name(p0)).Click();
>
> OR
>
> driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,p0)]")).Click();

And I have no idea how to make it work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to include the string contents of the parameter in the XPath query?

This should work:

```
var xPathQuery = String.Format("//a[contains(.,'{0}')]", p0);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathQuery)).Click();
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now I see, it was easy :) Thank yoo very much!

Comment: done. I have to wait 15 minutes after asking, I think

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, but that kind of way of building the expression is vulnerable to Xpath injection, look for Xpath precompiled queries (prepared statement brother :) ).

They give you a security and performance advantage.

Comment: You should provide an answer that solves this problem using prepared statements, rather than just telling them what to do.